# "Folk size" guitar: equivalent to 000 body type?

Tags: acoustic-guitar, styles

When an acoustic guitar is referred to as a "folk (size) guitar" ([example](http://www.simonandpatrick.com/songsmithfolk.htm)), is this simply an informal way of saying that it's of the [000 body type](http://www.musicradar.com/tuition/guitars/the-acoustic-guitar-body-shapes-guide-557230/3)? Are OM guitars also considered to be folk size?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes.

There is no standards body that regulates the names of guitar sizes/styles. For electric guitars, people often use the names of Gibson and Fender shapes ("Strat", "Tele", "SG", "Les Paul") and for acoustics, people often use the names used by Martin ("0", "00", "000", "OM").

One manufacturer might happen to use the word "folk" for a guitar that's similar in size and shape to a Martin 000.

However, it would be unwise to rely on it. Find the actual measurements of the guitar.

Of course, what actually matters is how the guitar sounds and feels. Unless you're experienced and know the risks, never buy a guitar without having tried it out.

Comment: Good to know. Makes purchasing cases a bit hit or miss if you don't have your guitar with you, though!